# Segue Constantly Reloading Screen

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase, authorization, visual-glitch

I'm new to coding and have been building an app for the last few weeks. I am a little stuck and not sure where to start looking. I have an app that can message between users, have social media pages, and show all users in the app. I have an addition tab that I would like to grant 2 users admin privileges. The other users have access to the same tab but see different things.

I have a json tree that looks like the following:

```
users 
 | 
 | 
 | 
 Jjhi848hjnef8 
       | 
       | 
       | 
      name: 
      email: 
      profileImageUrl: 
      ETC:
```

I also have a messages tree, as well as user messages tree. I don't want to have to make a new json tree with users and then setup up sub categories of roles because I want all users to be able to message each other and have access to the same stuff except one view controller in the tabbed app. Is there a way to accomplish this cleanly/effectively so I don't have to recode messages, profile, and all users tab?

Here is the code I am trying to run:

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

class ToDoViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()

checkIfAdmin()

}

func checkIfAdmin() {

    Database.database().reference().child("users").child(Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid).child("userType").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: {
     (snapshot) in

     switch snapshot.value as! String {
     // If our user is admin...
             case "Admin":
                 // ...redirect to the admin page
                guard let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "AdminVC") else { return }
                 vc.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
                 self.present(vc, animated: true)
             // If out user is a regular user...
             case "Talent":
                 // ...redirect to the talent page
                 guard let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "TalentVC") else { return }
                 vc.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
                 self.present(vc, animated: true)
             // If the type wasn't found...
             default:
         // ...print an error
         print("Error: Couldn't find type for user")
     }
   })
 }
}
```

My userType node has either Admin or Talent as the value. I am trying to get users that have been marked admin to see a specific view controller in my tab controller. I now can see the different pages but I am getting a glitch where it shows the view controller modally and it is constantly reloading the page and won't stop moving. If I turn animation to false it gets stuck and won't allow for any interactivity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to tell why that happens just by looking at this code snippet.
I think you should upload also the code of the TalentVC view controller

Comment: I figured out that the view controllers had the ToDo's view controller swift file. But when it loads the new designated controller but it doesn't have the navigation bar and it is missing the table bar. Any suggestions?

Comment: From what I can understand, your issue is that the viewController that is displayed when the segue is performed doesn't have a navbar or a tabbar. If that's the case, just drag a nav bar and a tab bar into the view of the view controller